# Expand limits in root finding scipy.optimize (bisection or brentq)

Tags: python, scipy, bisection

I want to find a root of a function. I know that the root exists but not where it can be on the real line, so if I give some upper and lower bound to scipy.optimize.brentq it is likely that there is no change in signs.

Is there any nice way to allow for the limits to expand if there is no sign change? R has an option expand limits that does so. Right now I am doing it manually but it does not seem the best approach.

Comment: Did you tryed to use numpy? check it [here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, in the sense that this functionality is not built into `scipy.optimize.brentq`. The philosophy is that you find the bracket first, then pass the bracket into `brentq`. There is a private function in SciPy 1.12 to help you find the bracket, though:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize._zeros_py import _bracket_root

def f(x):
    return x - 1.5

res = _bracket_root(f, 2, 3)
res
```

produces:

```
     success: True
      status: 0
          xl: 1.0
          xr: 2.0
         nit: 1
        nfev: 4
          fl: -0.5
          fr: 0.5
```

The `xl` and `xr` attributes form a bracket, which you can pass into `brentq`.

```py
from scipy.optimize import brentq
brentq(f, res.xl, res.xr)
# 1.5
```

The private function will almost certainly have moved to a different location in SciPy 1.13, but it should probably become public at some point soon.